# How do I get a license tag in Nuget gallery?

Tags: nuget

Looking at e.g. the [jQuery Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery) there is a "license details" panel at the bottom of the left column, saying that jQuery is licensed under an MIT license.

How do I get such a "license details" for my [own project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices/) that is licensed under LGPL?

The license link of my nuget package points to the `LICENSE` file in the GitHub repo of the project. From what I've been able to find out the "license details" is somehow automatically derived from the linked license file, but it doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: I was going to suggest you try linking to the raw license text instead of the github page but the license details works for the older 0.1 version of your NuGet package which has the same link.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I hadn't seen that the previous version had the correct tag. Might be worth linking to the raw license file though if it makes detection easier. Will try with next version.

Answer (score 0):

Its bit late for the answer, yet it might help some else.

On nuget site there is guide how to create a nuget package

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package

This site does have example of .nuspec file, where you can specify link to the license you wish to have your project under.

To choose appropriate license, have a look here:
http://choosealicense.com/